# Почему typeahead by bassjobsen может выдавать фризы?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

Файл cities.json (~12MB)

Есть такой код.
Он работает так, как нужно, но если очень быстро удалять через backspace и быстро начинать вводить новые данные в инпут он начинает крашить браузер. Он отвисает, но это ведь никуда не годится.

Используется [эта](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/README.md) версия typeAhead.

```
 $.get("cities.json", function(data){
 $("#choiseCityName").typeahead({ source:data,
    displayText: function (item) {
       return item.name;
    },
    afterSelect: function(item) {
    return weather.showCityWeather($("#choiseCityName").val())
    },
    highlighter: function(item, data) {
       return `<div> ${item} <strong>${data.country}</strong></div>`
    }
  });
 },'json')
```

Comment: добавь параметр `delay`

Comment: @Grundy все так же, и мне кажется он фризит еще когда поле становится пустым, но backspace еще нажат или если нажать когда поле пустое

Comment: сколько элементов в массиве?

Comment: @Grundy около 100к

Comment: добавь пример одного объекта

Comment: { "country": "ru","city": "Moscow", "lat":"1383","lon":"83387"} к примеру.